# Android layout: one on left, one on right, one on center?

Tags: android, layout, center

I need such a layout:

[image]

The button1 is on the left, the button3 is on the right, and button2 is on the center. And all of them on the middle of vertical direction.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout`.

Button #1 has

- `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`
- `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`.

Button #2: has

- `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

Button #3 has

- `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`
- `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`.